# Unable to Execute VLC from PHP

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2, php, vlc

I am running uBuntu 12.04.3, 32 bit OS on a 8 CPU, 8GB RAM 64-bit Intel Xeon machine. I have installed all backports as well.

I have this problem which is eating my head for the last 3 days. I created a play.sh file with the following code...

Code:

```
#! /bin/sh 

vlc -vvv sasural.ts
```

Where sasural.ts is a video file that resides under home and in the same level as Apache. I am invoking the .sh file by using the following PHP code...

Code:

`shell_exec('play.sh');`

I also tried both the exec() / system() methods to invoke the .sh file.

Whenever I do so, I get the following message...

```
VLC media player 2.2.0-git Weatherwax Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help. > Shutting down.
```

play.sh works if I execute it from the terminal command prompt outside of the PHP code. I guess I am doing something wrong when I invoke it from within PHP.

I have performed the following tasks...

1. Given Apache Root Access
2. Linked all folders to Apache

Comment: What for is `-vvv` option? I use `VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower` and I have no problem.

Comment: Try hardcoding the path to the shell script - it's possible that while it's in the same directory as apache, it isn't in the same directory as where the PHP interpreter runs from

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: I cannot use any VLC version under 2.1. My problem is that I have to get the media files from a server which only accepts https:// and any version under 2.1 does not allow manual acceptance / storage of certificates. Try navigating to https://122.160.220.83/bharti/bharti/PREVIEW/sasural.ts and let me know if it shows on your VLC.

Comment: No, it shows only strange characters.

Comment: I'm willing to think that `vlc` don't have any idea the file is there hence it only shows version then shutdown. What's the path `$PWD` the script reports?

Comment: Double checking - *where* are you expecting VLC to open? On the client or on the server? If you want it on the client, you won't be able to solve this with PHP

Comment: @jackweirdy That's not double-checking, that's just plain checking. He hasn't said once what the desired behavior is; he says it "works" from the terminal but not what it _does_.

Comment: I am supposed to play this file on a client (VLC or other media player) on an independent PC via the internet (The server has a public IP). When I said it works, I mean that when I run the shell script manually (Via the command line) it successfully streams the file out of a port which could be picked up by a client media player connecting to that particular port on the server. Currently I am testing this for broadcast and multicast. Once successful I will try to implement this for Video on Demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gentlemen,

I have been able to solve this issue by using the following steps...

- Install vlc nox version
- In the PHP file:
    echo shell_exec("sh /var/www/play1.sh");
- In the play1.sh file:
    #!/bin/sh
    vlc -Idummy /var/www/media.ts --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:1935/}'
- Invoke the PHP file via a browser and VLC will start streaming to port 1935

To access the file from the client end...

1) Point VLC or any media player to the URL + Port. Ex. http://www.something.com:1935
2) The client player will start to receive the file and play it back.

Now the next step is to enable this file on demand. Will post how I did that as well so stay tuned!!

Thank you everybody who have helped me in solving this problem. I have added +reps wherever it was possible.

Answer (score 4):

Done it :)

That was fun :D

prerequisites: vlc must already be running
fifo file must exist
The below will set this up:

```
mkfifo /tmp/vlcfifo
chmod a+rw /tmp/vlcfifo
tail -f /tmp/vlcfifo | nohup vlc --intf rc &
```

in the php file:

```
<?php
passthru('echo "add /path/to/video.avi" | tee /tmp/vlcfifo');
?>
```

Give that a try :)

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow morning! I hope this will work for the headless noX (Non GUI) version of VLC.

Answer (score 2):

In your script, before you launch vlc, have the line: `export DISPLAY=:0`

This should launch it in your primary X session, assuming the webserver is running on the same box as your X session.

You will also need to do something with sound if you require it. Like a remote ALSA or Pulseaudio server.

Comment: Assuming there is an X session on the system.  This might be a server without a GUI.

Comment: Hey Thanks! i will try this out first thing tomorrow! I really - really hope this works! By the way this IS a headless (Non-GUI) server. Which also basically means that I have the noX version of VLC installed on it. Do you think this still could be the solutions?

Comment: Using a headless server is fine, but you do need the basic X libs and the X version of VLC. The DISPLAY environment variable is telling you which X server to connect to. It's an easy way to display any X application on different X displays, and it doesn't have to be the same host either. I do this through SSH X11 forwarding all the time. I guess knowing more on what you are attempting to do would help, I just have picked up, "launching the GUI version of VLC through an Apache (I assume) PHP page."